# What is the optimal pattern to ensure a priority API gets cycles over its related (non-priority) API?

Tags: web-services, web-api

I have two synchronous web APIs that perform the same work but one needs to be prioritized over the other (the former is called from a client, whereas the latter is a caching optimization for before a client calls)

Constraints:

1. Both APIs have access to the same resources (such as VMs and storage) and I can't add more resources
2. Both APIs must remain synchronous
3. I want to ensure the priority API takes precedence over the optimization API, but preferably not starve either
4. APIs are stateless

Question:
What is the appropriate pattern to ensure the priority API always gets cycles without starving either API? Would a throttling mechanism, where the priority API gets much more tokens than the optimization API, be appropriate?

Comment: Shall we assume that the caching optimization api is invoked synchronously during some other client API call? Or should we assume that the caching optimization API call is invoked by a background process, timer, or other such source?

Comment: In order for this prioritization to have value, there has to be contention for some resource. On what resources(s) are you seeing contention that makes a significant difference to clients or to you?

Comment: @joshp - My question description was over-simplified. There's a middle-man service that attempts to cache data for a client. That caching is achieved via calling my optimization API. If the client calls the middle-man before caching can happen, the middle-man calls the priority API for immediate retrieval.

Comment: @joshp - Contention is that I only have so many VMs that handle these API calls. Because it's possible the middle-man may make optimization API calls in large batches, that risks starving the priority endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can have the middleman keep track of how many VMs are doing what (not unlike the old Apache HTTP server spawning strategy).

At every moment, an optimization API may be called only if enough free VMs exist (or are expected to exist within a reasonable time slice, if the call start time and average call duration are known) to cover any need for high priority calls. This ensures that incoming high priority calls will be, indeed, immediately served (this assumes there is no other contention where we could place a priority broker).

You can keep track of the actual free pool size at every moment to minimize the number of under-loaded VMs (i.e., if with X free VMs 100% of high priority calls are always dispatched, you can decrease X by 1, and continue doing so on until you're hovering around a comfortable figure, say 95%).

This on the other hand means that your middleman cannot make calls in batches, unless very many VMs are free. Not being able to batch calls *might* impact performances, while on the other hand keeping too many VMs free surely will.

Also, you can keep track of which call is under way - if a call has already been issued, and a high priority request for the same parameters comes through, it is probably more convenient to wait for the previous call to terminate than to dispatch immediately the request to a free VM.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the middle-man (apologies for not specifying that earlier). When an API is called, it lacks any context on whether other VMs are free. The reason I proposed throttling was to try to leverage load balancing.